# Webmin local development with name based virtualhosts

Tags: linux, virtualhost, webmin

Hi i am trying to name based virtual hosts for my localhost.I was using wamp with name based virtualhost before but now im working on ubuntu.I thought webmin can be easy but when i create first virtual host all requests redirecting first virtual host even localhost,second virtualhost and phpmyadmin.

So how can i set webmin for reach each of them separately.

hosts config

```
127.0.0.1 www.adres1.com #working fine
127.0.0.1 adres1.com #working fine
127.0.0.1 www.adres2.com
127.0.0.1 adres2.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are using a local server and your all domain will by default search 127.0.0.1 or your IP. So untill you declair them as CNAME in your zone file or do a entry in host file, they all will work as alias of a single domain.  Thanks... :)